# pointer declared in beginning of scope is "undeclared"

Tags: c

my compiler and I can't agree on a declaration..

```
game *copyGame(game *game) {
  game *copy = newGame(game->size);

  copy->size = game->size;

  int x, y;
  for (x = 0; x < game->size; x++)
    for (y = 0; y < game->size; y++)
      copy->board[x][y] = game->board[x][y];

  return copy;
}
```

when compiled

```
game.c:14:9: error: use of undeclared identifier 'copy'
  game *copy = newGame(game->size);
        ^
game.c:16:3: error: use of undeclared identifier 'copy'
  copy->size = game->size;
  ^
game.c:17:3: error: use of undeclared identifier 'copy'
  copy->board = newBoard(game->size);
  ^
game.c:22:7: error: use of undeclared identifier 'copy'
      copy->board[x][y] = game->board[x][y];
      ^
game.c:24:10: error: use of undeclared identifier 'copy'
  return copy;
```

same happens when I try

```
game *copyGame(game *game) {
  game *copy;
  copy = newGame(game->size);
```

The compiler doesn't complain about

```
game *newGame(int size) {
  game *g = (game*) malloc(sizeof(game));

  g->size = size;
  g->board = newBoard(size);

  return g;
}
```

question: why is 'copy' undeclared?

Comment: Try renaming it? Maybe there's a name-clash somewhere.

Comment: That's not how `new` works, is it?

Comment: when you want a dynamically allocated struct you have to write a "new" function in C - there is no objects or "new"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Name capture.  C uses the same scopes for types and variables.  Re-name your parameter

```
game *game
```

to something else, such as

```
game *mygame
```